# Electron: How do I get the selected text from a focused window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, clipboard

I'm building my first electron app and try to rebuild my old program with nodejs (my previous programm was built in autoit).

My app reacts to a hotkey from the user and should copy and process selected text from another application.

My current problem is that this process works, but takes about 5 seconds until I have the text from the clipboard.

Could you please help me optimize this process? I would like to have a short reaction time without the user noticing. Especially because my app blocks completely during this time.

My app waits for the hotkey and launches from my clipboard class the method `clipboard.getClipboardNew()`.

This function clears the clipboard from windows and start to send `STRG+C` to copy the current selected text. Afterwards I check several times whether something has landed in the clipboard.

```
main.js
```

```js
const ioHook = require('iohook')
const clipboardClass = require('./modules/ClipboardClass')
let clipboard = new clipboardClass()
[...]
app.on('ready', () => {

    // Hotkey wird über ioHook Package registriert
    //const globalHotkey = ioHook.registerShortcut([29, 0], (keys) => {
    const globalHotkey = ioHook.registerShortcut([29, 45], (keys) => { // STRG+X
        // Ausgelesenes Clipboard wird an unseren Renderer Process geschickt
        events.sendRenderer(win, 'main-process', 'renderer-process', 'hotkeyEvent', clipboard.getClipboardSaved())
    })
    ioHook.start()  // Register and start hook >> pass true to start in DEBUG mode.

    // Erstellt unsere Electron GUI
    createWindow()
})
```

```
ClipboardClass.js
```

```js
'use strict';
const { clipboard  } = require('electron')
const ks = require('node-key-sender')
const sleep = require('./SleepModule')

/**
 * Clipboard Class
 * Verwaltet das Clipboard
 */
class ClipboardClass {
    constructor() {
        this.clipboard = ""
        this.clipboardOld = ""
        this.GetClipTries = 100
    }

    // Setzt neuen Inhalt ins Clipboard
    setClipboard(newContent) {
        this.clipboardOld = this.clipboard          // Speichert alten Inhalt 
        this.clipboard = newContent                 // Setzt neuen Inhalt in Objektspeicher
        clipboard.writeText(newContent)             // Setzt neuen Clipboard Inhalt
        return true
    }

    // Gibt gespeicherten Inhalt zurück
    getClipboardNew() {
        // Speichert alten Inhalt und leert Windows Clipboard / letzten gespeicherten Inhalt
        this.clipboardOld = this.clipboard
        clipboard.writeText("")
        this.clipboard = ""

        // Sendet STRG+C um markierten Text ins Clipboard zu laden
        this.loadClipboard()
        
        // Wiederholt mehrmals die Clipboard Abfrage
        for (var i = 0; i < this.GetClipTries; i++) {
            this.clipboard = clipboard.readText()           // Liest aktuellen Inhalt aus dem Clipboard

            // Debug Info
            console.log(----:----:----:----:----)
            console.log('Versuch Nr.: '+i)
            console.log('Clipboard: '+this.clipboard)
            console.log(----:----:----:----:----)

            // Unterbricht die Schleife wenn Inhalt erkannt wurde, oder wartet bis zur nächsten Prüfung
            if (this.clipboard != "") { break }             
            sleep.msleep(100)
        }
        return this.clipboard
    }

    // Gibt vorherigen gespeicherten Inhalt zurück
    getClipboardSaved() {
        return this.clipboard
    }

    // Gibt vorherigen gespeicherten Inhalt zurück
    getClipboardOld() {
        return this.clipboardOld
    }
    
    // Sendet STRG+C um markierten Text ins Clipboard zu laden
    loadClipboard() {
        ks.sendCombination(['control', 'c'])
        return true
    }
}
module.exports = ClipboardClass;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm developing an electron app that needs to do something similar to what you're trying to do here. Did you ever find an acceptable solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi... not really. I've not found a suitable option with node. However, I use a different method. I spawn a small autoit script in my electron main process. This script sends a CTRL+C, waits until windows has the text in the clipboard, reads it out, closes itself and then sends it back via stdout. My main process in electron gets the selected text in an callback and I can work with it. The whole process takes less than a second. Hardly noticeable for the user. Works perfectly, except that I would have preferred to have it entirely in nodejs.

Comment: However, instead of autoit, you could also spawn a powershell script that does the same thing.

Comment: I was afraid it would come to this. Thank you for sharing your approach. I really appreciate it.